# How do I comprae connecting to databse using ADO.Net and dapper and EF?

Tags: c#

I have done some experiment to test speed of connecting to db using 4 methods

1- Dapper using generic

2- dapper using SP

3- Ado.Net

4- EF

```
*IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection("server=.;database=MSSTART;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
            db.Open();
            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
            watch.Start();
            // Reading Db from Dapper using Casting;
            var r = db.Query<Entity.Account>("Select * From Account").ToList();
            watch.Stop();
            TimeSpan timeSpan = watch.Elapsed;


            Stopwatch watch2 = new Stopwatch();
            watch2.Start();
            // Reading Db from Dapper using SP;
            var c3 = db.Query<Entity.Account>("GetAccounts", null, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, commandTimeout: 30);
            watch2.Stop();
            TimeSpan timeSpan2 = watch2.Elapsed;


            Stopwatch watch3 = new Stopwatch();
            watch3.Start();
            // Reading Db from ADO.NET;
            var entity = accountRepository.GetAccounts();
            watch3.Stop();
            TimeSpan timeSpan3 = watch3.Elapsed;


            Stopwatch watch4 = new Stopwatch();
            watch4.Start();
            // Reading Db from EF;
            var result = accountEfRepositoryInterface.GetAll();
            watch4.Stop();
            TimeSpan timeSpan4 = watch4.Elapsed;
```

Why I am getting EF is faster than ADO.Net ?

Any reason ?

Here is the api

http://mohammad.co.nz/MSTRATAPI/api/Account/List

Comment: Maybe `accountRepository` is lazily initialized?

Comment: Did you check with the Profiler the exact query text that the database is executing?. If the queries are the same a lot of work is cached inside the db engine

Comment: define what you mean by "ADO.Net" ... you can use `IDataReader` to convert to some model and this should be faster ... you may also use `DataTable ` and then, I don't know, it may be slower ... also tests should be runned multiple times ... you may just mesuring time spended on SQL server and not your code ...

Comment: @Steve Even changing the order of the calls can affect the timing due to server caching of request results.

Comment: in Ado.Net I am using datareader

Comment: also ... your `accountEfRepositoryInterface.GetAll` may not query at all (without iteration it may only create query)

Comment: @Selvin what u mean ?

Comment: Exactly what I written - IQueryable may be not executed until you do some iteration on it

Comment: @Selvin u are right

Comment: It's off topic to compare products by ef will be slowest... But it's more than simple mapper.... Ado will be fastest... But it takes more code... Dapper would be best as you have simply mapping but without additional coding... Of course when you don't need features from EF

Comment: @Selvin you are right, Ado.net is faster

Comment: @Selvin accountEfRepositoryInterface.GetAll was not hitting the db

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the accountEfRepositoryInterface which was not hitting the DB. Also I removed the second one

So now I am getting dapper is faster. Stopwatch watch2 = new

```
Stopwatch();
            watch2.Start();
            // Reading Db from Dapper using SP;
            var c3 = db.Query<Entity.Account>("GetAccounts", null, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, commandTimeout: 30);
            watch2.Stop();
            TimeSpan timeSpan2 = watch2.Elapsed;
```

To remove caching.

Now I am getting sometimes ado.net faster, sometimes dapper